# how to get interval mathematically

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization, mathematical-expressions

If I have `n` of elements (e.g `n=100`)

```
int n=100; 
int[] n=new  int[n];
System.out.print("Enter something:");
Integer input =(Integer) System.console().readLine();
```

And I divide `n` to intervals (e.g `partitioning=10`)

So in this case I have `10` intervals: `[0,9]`,`[10,19]`,`[20,29]`...`[90,100]`

**The question is:**

If user input a element, how to get its interval? 
I want to know if this number located in *first* 10 or in *second* ten or *third*...

But without using switch or for loop. I want it mathematically, with equations.

Comment: Your question seems a bit unclear to me. Please clarify.

Comment: i have n of elements  for example n=100 , The user will give me number between [0,100] .I want to distribute this number.I want to know if this number located in first 10 or second 10 or third. what is equation?

Comment: You know how to get the interval from its index. (0th is [0*10, 0*10 + (10 - 1)], 1st is  [1*10, 1*10 + (10 - 1)], ...) Is not finding the index a simple euclidian division?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just divide the number by 10 using [`Integer Division`](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) and add 1:

```
bucket number = n / 10 + 1
```

Comment: what is n ? if you mean the size of array?this is not what iam mean

Comment: i mean if user enter number i have to code switch if 0<number<10 then first interval  , if 10<number<20 then second interval and so on ..But i want mathematical equation which input the number to it with n and 10 and the result will be first interval or second or  such.

Comment: `n` is the number entered by the user.

Comment: please <can you help me for this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/34866621/5733631